# "Issues" loading MANY featured images on a single page (custom template)

Tags: templates, featured-post

I have a page that loads a lot of featured items in a grid. There are up to 56 images loading, and it does have a bit of a delay.
This is the code as it runs now:

```
if( count( $postslist ) > 0 ) {
  foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
  ?> 
  <div class='oneCell'>
    <?php 
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($this_post->ID, 'full size'); 
    $imageSrc = substr($image, strpos($image, "src") + 5);
    $imageSrc = substr($imageSrc, 0, strPos($imageSrc, "\""));
    $finalImage = "<img class='lazy' src='/images/grey.png' data-original='";
    $finalImage .= $imageSrc . "' />";
    $lastImage = "<a href='";
    $lastImage .= catch_that_image();
    $lastImage .= "'>";
    $lastImage .= $finalImage;
    $lastImage .= "</a>";
    echo $lastImage;
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php 
  $currentCount = $currentCount + 1;
  endforeach;
}
```

I understand there are issues with the code, basically hitting the database once for every image in a loop, which is causing the slowness.

Can anyone help me out with a solution to speed up the loading? My thought is grabbing everything from the database all at once and displaying it from there, but I have yet to figure out how to handle that.

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry, I should have explained this a bit more:

The get_the_post_thumbnail is asking for the fullsize image because the fullsize image is what it needs (189x189). The featured image in the post is that image, and will always be 189x189.

catch_that_image() just grabs the first (and only) image in the post body to be displayed when the user clicks on the featured image (thumbnail) using a js library (magnific-popup.js).

Edit 2:

It looks like my issue is database related. The calls are too slow to do one at a time (since there are so many). Is there a way to get everything back in one call then process it from there?

Comment: What does `catch_that_image()`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that part. I've edited the post to explain what that does.

Comment: That function is probably your bottle neck.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Any tips on how to get all the photos from the posts so they can be displayed quickly?

Comment: either use a caching plugin, or generate your markup on the back end when a post is added or updated and save it in an option.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **eager loading** or **cache** or both.

### Eager loading

Have a look to this pseudo-code:

```
$ids = get_ids_from_a_db_table();
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
  $row = get_row_from_foreign_table_using( $id );
  echo "Row title for the ID: $id is $row->title";
}
```

If the number of `$ids` is `n` than this simple code runs `n+1` queries, the first to load the ids, then one for each id.

You code is even worse, it run 2 queries for every id, one to get attachment post object, one to get attachemnt url (is WordPress, not you, really)

So you run 2n+1 queries...

Eager loading, referred to a db query, is the way you solve the n+1 (or 2n+1) queries problem by querying in only **one** db request all the data you need (normally is done using proper `JOIN` + `WHERE` )

```
$data = get_data_from_joined_db_tables();
foreach ( $data as $row ) {
  echo "Row title for the ID: $row->id is $row->title";
}
```

How do that in WordPress? You need two things:

- add proper join and where clauses to merge the post meta table
- filter the fields returned by `WP_Query` to include meta table fields

Both can be done using query filters, here a class extending `WP_Query` that do that:

```
class Thumb_Query extends WP_Query {

  protected static $args = array( 'nopaging' => TRUE );

  public function __construct( $args = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $args ) ) $args = self::$args; // defaults
    parent::__construct( $args );
  }

  public function get_posts() {
    add_filter('posts_clauses', array( __CLASS__, 'thumb_filters') );
    $results = parent::get_posts();
    remove_filter('posts_clauses', array( __CLASS__, 'thumb_filters') );
    return $this->parse_images( $results );
  }

  public static function thumb_filters( $pieces ) {
    $meta = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->postmeta;
    $posts = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts;
    $pieces['fields'] .= ", thumbs.meta_value as thumb_id";
    $pieces['fields'] .= ", imgs.post_title as thumb_title";
    $pieces['fields'] .= ", imgdata.meta_value as thumb_file";
    $pieces['join'] .= "INNER JOIN {$meta} thumbs ON ({$posts}.ID = thumbs.post_id)";
    $pieces['join'] .= " INNER JOIN {$posts} imgs ON (thumbs.meta_value = imgs.ID)";
    $pieces['join'] .= " INNER JOIN {$meta} imgdata ON (imgs.ID = imgdata.post_id)";
    $where = " AND ( thumbs.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND ";
    $where .= " CAST( thumbs.meta_value AS SIGNED ) > 0 )";
    $where .= " AND ( imgdata.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' )";
    $pieces['where'] .= $where;
    $pieces['groupby'] = " {$posts}.ID";
    return $pieces;
  }

  protected function parse_images( $rows ) {
    $exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    foreach ( $rows as $i => $row ) {
       $urls = wp_extract_urls( $row->post_content );
       $img = FALSE;
       while ( ! $img && ! empty($urls) ) {
         $url = array_shift($urls);
         $ext = strtolower ( pathinfo( $url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
         if ( in_array( $ext, $exts ) ) $img = $url;
       }
       $rows[$i]->thumb_link = $img ? $img : '#';
    }
  }
}
```

This class extends `WP_Query`, so accepts same things of its parent but add some filters to change the eager loading thumnail post id, thumnail post name and thumbnail file path.

So if your query returns 50 posts, to display thumbnails you run 101 (2n+1) queries, my class you runs only 1 query.

In addition before output the results, the class parse all the rows, and extract first image url from post content and remove the filter added.

### How to use

Use the standard `WP_Query` arguments:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
  'category_name' => 'featured',
  'posts_per_page' => 50
);
```

But use `Thumb_Query` instead of `WP_Query`

```
$portfolio = new Thumb_Query( $args );
```

Then loop and output:

```
if ( $portfolio->have_posts() ) {
  $u = wp_upload_dir();
  global $post;
  foreach( $portfolio->posts as $post ) { 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $f = '<div class="oneCell"><a href="%s" title="%s">';
    $f .= '<img class="lazy" alt="%s" width="189" src="%s" data-original="%s"/>';
    $f .= '</a></div>';
    $title = esc_attr( get_the_title() );
    printf( $f,
      esc_url( $post->thumb_link ),
      $title, $title,
      esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/grey.png'  ),
      esc_url( trailingslashit($u['baseurl']) . $post->thumb_file )
    );
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Inside the loop you have access to all standard post properties, but every post has additional 4 properties:

- `$post->thumb_id` the thumbnail attachment id
- `$post->thumb_title` the thumbnail attachment title
- `$post->thumb_file` the thumbnail file relative to uploads folder, something like `'/2014/04/myfile.jpg'`
- `$post->thumb_link` the full url of the first image in post content or '#' if no image found

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to understand what you have done. One of my concerns is using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and `catch_that_image()` together in the same code as you have done. I have knowledge of `catch_that_image()` function and have used it before. It is a nice-to-know-function that is usually used by coders to retrieve the first image to display it in the excerpt. How ever, there are better ways to get the same result without `catch_that_image()`. I do really think that it slows down your site as it is an outside function that runs separately from the loop, specially if you need to retrieve 56 images. `catch_that_image()` needs to run on every post to retrieve the image, so it is executed 56 times. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

I don't know what your loop looks like, but that seems to be bit of a mess. I think the best way to go here is by using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in conjuction with [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to construct your loop.

In `WP_Query` you will only need to pass one argument to make this work, `posts_per_page`. You will need to set this to `1`, otherwise you will get the same image multiple times.

Next is to run the loop, and filter out all the images attached to a post using `post_type` and `post_mime_type`. Wordpress saves all attachments as a [`post type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Not all attachments are images, so it needs to be specified that only attachments that are images should be returned. This is specified by [`post_mime_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children).

[`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) will be used to return these images at the specified size, in your code this will be the full size featured image.

This all done and dusted, the full loop will look something like this

```
<?php 
    $new_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    ));

        while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

            $args = array (
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => 56,
                'status' => 'publish',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'parent' => $post->ID
            ); 

            $attachments = get_posts($args);

            if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    echo '<div class="oneCell">';
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            };

        endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

You just need to change the arguments to suite your exact needs, but I hope this is a basic platform that you need and can work from and that this really helps a lot with speed. Enjoy.

**Edit**
Don't forget to reset the query using `wp_reset_postdata();`